# "Какой-нибудь объект/объекты". Оформление конструкции, относящейся одновременно к единственному и множественному числу?

Tags: орфография, единственное-множественное-число

Мне нужно перевести предложение с английского языка в котором есть словосочетание "some object(s)" - "какой-нибудь объект(ы)". В английском нет проблемы с подобным написанием, так-как some может относиться как к множественному, так и к единственному числу, но я без понятия как правильно записать перевод по-русски. 
"Какой-нибудь объект(ы)"? 
"Какой(ие)-нибудь объект(ы)"? 
"Какой(какие)-нибудь объект(ы)"?

Comment: Если у вас в контексте множественное число (судя по названию вопроса), то какие-нибудь объекты.

Comment: Ваш заголовок не совсем соответствует смыслу вопроса. Я беру на себя смелость поправить, вы сможете можете отменить мою правку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я в таких случаях обычно пишу **"какие-нибудь объект(ы)"**.
Это связано с тем, что человек при чтении все равно подсознательно проговаривает более длинную версию слова **"объект(ы)"** (с буквой **"ы"**), поэтому форма слова **"какой"**/**"какие"** должна согласовываться именно с ней.
А наличия скобок вокруг **"ы"** и так достаточно для того, чтобы выразить факультативность множественного числа, поэтому никаких дополнительный языковых средств здесь не нужно.

Answer (score 1):

По-русски лучше сказать так: "какой-нибудь объект или объекты".

Answer (score 1):

Я бы порекомедовал форму ***какой-нибудь объект (объекты)*** или ***какие-нибудь объекты (объект)***. Второе, пожалуй, даже лучше.

Суть предложения в том, что при таком написании несогласованность грамматических форм определения и определяемого не бросается в глаза и воспринимается как нечто нормальное. Вариант "объект(ы)" не обладает в полной мере этим свойством.

Ну а в очень серьезных, юридически значимых текстах тем более надо писать полностью: ***какой-нибудь объект (какие-нибудь объекты)***. Впрочем, само слово "какой-нибудь" - явно не из юридического лексикона, это просто общая рекомендация для подобных случаев.

В самом же примитивном, бытовом тексте, можно вообще не использовать оговорки на единственное число - "какие-нибудь объекты", что на бытовом языке вполне может означать и единичный экземпляр такого объекта.

(+) Дополнение. Все сказанное не совсем годится на случай переводного текста. Дело все в том, что в английском указанная запись делает случаи единственного и множественного числа не только грамматически правильными, но и семантически равноправными. А в русском, как ни крути, один вариант все равно получится главным. Тут надо будет уже решать по английскому контексту, при необходимости даже проконсультировавшись со специалистом. Возможно, что сокращенная запись вообще окажется неприемлемой. Тогда ничего другого не останется, как писать полностью, жертвуя краткостью ради точности: ***какой-нибудь объект или какие-нибудь объекты.*** Не знаю, насколько частой может быть такая ситуация, что по-другому нельзя, но она точно реальна при нотариальном переводе.

(++) Есть еще вариант использования косой черты ("слеша) вместо скобок - как в моей версии заголовка, но он на русском не слишком популярен вне сугубо технических текстов. К тому же в английском варианты со скобками и слешем используются оба, и иногда несут несколько разный смысл, поэтому заменять при переводе одно другим я бы не рекомендовал.

Comment: Спасибо за хороший развернутый ответ. Вариант "какие-нибудь объекты (объект)" я определенно возьму на заметку, но ответ от Ivan Olshansky лучше всего подходит под мой конкретный случай.

Comment: @yakrobat - ну как скажете, хозяин-барин )))). Понимаете в чем штука, здесь вопросы и ответы принято давать так, чтобы они были самодостаточны, а о том, что там у вас за конкретный случай никто не знает.  Естественно, я исходил из того, что надо покрыть вопрос так, как он задан, а не так, как задумывался... Но это так, на будущее. Давайте необходимый контекст - сэкономите и наше время и свое - на чтение.